# VK API throught C++ Boost

Tags: c++, boost, vk

how to open socket for connecting to VK API, this code works good with other resources, but gives `APPCRASH` with `api.vk.com`. In browser it works with `http`, hence it should work here, and problem is not in 'http`, or am I wrong? Help!

P.S. I'm new to Boost and VK API, so if you can, explain it in details, thank you.

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query("api.vk.com", "http");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator, error);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess that `APPCRASH` is an interpretation, please provide the facts instead. Also, you know that not all iterators are dereferencable, right?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `APPCRASH` might be a thing you see in the Windows event log.

From that, I formed the hypothesis that you might be running this code in a windows service context.

Windows services do not have network access by default.

This means the DNS lookup may fail. You get an exception, e.g. `resolve: Host not found (authoritative)`. This is what happens in a Linux console when I purposefully change the domain name to a nonexisting TLD:

```
$ ./test
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Because you don't handle the exception or check for errors, the program is abnormally terminated.

### Fixed Demo

Note:

- I opted to handle errors rather than exceptions.
- You failed to loop through the query results (using only the first without even checking whether it was valid)
- Coliru, much like a restricted windows service, does not allow network connectivity outside the loopback adaptor either, so it shows a proper error

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10c6e9a98ebe8f17)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

    // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query("api.vk.com", "http");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query, error), last;

    if (!error) {

        // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);

        for (;endpoint_iterator != last; ++endpoint_iterator) {
            socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator, error);
            if (!error) {
                std::cout << "Successfully connected to " << endpoint_iterator->endpoint() << "\n";
                break; // found working endpoint
            } else {
                std::cout << "Skipped " << endpoint_iterator->endpoint() << " - not connecting\n";
            }
        }
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << error.message() << "\n";
        return 255;
    }
}
```

On my system it prints

```
Successfully connected to 87.240.131.97:80
```

Comment: Provided fixed up sample with error handling and reporting

Comment: On my system it gives:  
`Skipped [2a00:bdc0:3:103:1:0:403:902]:80 - not connecting`  
`Skipped [2a00:bdc0:3:103:1:0:403:901]:80 - not connecting`  
`Skipped [2a00:bdc0:3:103:1:0:403:900]:80 - not connecting`  
`Skipped 87.240.131.119:80 - not connecting`  
`Skipped 87.240.131.120:80 - not connecting`  `Skipped 87.240.131.118:80 - not connecting`

Comment: I'd check firewalls. If the browser works, it likely goes through the proxy. Consider using libcurl or so to get proxy support.

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed my DNS server and it works:  `Successfully connected to 87.240.131.119:80`